# JS - ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get data from the sochain blockchain api using javascript but when I run my code i get the error:

```
ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/Main.js:1:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

So my question is what am I doing wrong why is fetch coming up with this error? My code is:

```
var json = fetch('https://sochain.com/api/v2/address/LTC/LMSuo8W7CiXs8oFs1sJh77AQ54tCZM42Ay');
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
document.write(obj["data"]["received_value"]);
```

Comment: What are you using? `fetch` should work. Are you using Node JS?

Comment: Is this node.js? If not, what browser/environment is this? Node doesn't have fetch, you need a library like node-fetch or some other polyfill.

Comment: Try the Axios package https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Comment: Im just using this compiler

Comment: https://paiza.io/projects/_BDmlB6wi4TZEWMZ8qawkg

Comment: @RichardCooper You're running it on Node JS instance in Paiza.io. Use [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) or [CodePen](https://codepen.io/) for running your code please. And here... [Paiza runs on Node JS not on Browser](https://i.imgur.com/VrB1bO2.png).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're running it on Node JS instance in Paiza.io. Use [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) or [CodePen](https://codepen.io/) for running your code please. And here... [Paiza runs on Node JS not on Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPUKS.png).

In your example, you need to use `fetch()` this way:

```js
fetch(
  "https://sochain.com/api/v2/address/LTC/LMSuo8W7CiXs8oFs1sJh77AQ54tCZM42Ay"
)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((obj) => document.write(obj["data"]["received_value"]));
```

Here's the Code Sandbox: [**exciting-bhaskara-sksve**](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-bhaskara-sksve?file=/src/index.js)

---

The `fetch()` API is a browser API implemented in the major browsers. If you are planning to use the same in the Node JS Runtime, then you have to make use of 3rd Party Fetch libraries like [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch).

Install [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch):

```sh
npm install node-fetch
```

Then include it in the code.

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
```

If you're trying to access plain text, then use:

```js
fetch('https://example.com/')
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(body => console.log(body));
```

If you're using JSON (**your solution here**), then use:

```js
fetch('https://sochain.com/api/v2/address/LTC/LMSuo8W7CiXs8oFs1sJh77AQ54tCZM42Ay')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));
```

---

Another alternative will be [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), which is a Promise based HTTP client for the browser and node.js. You have an awesome [**Axios Cheat Sheet**](https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/Axios.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index) available for common uses.

Install [`axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios):

```sh
npm install axios
```

Then include it in the code.

```js
const axios = require('axios');
```

For your case, you can do:

```js
axios.get('https://sochain.com/api/v2/address/LTC/LMSuo8W7CiXs8oFs1sJh77AQ54tCZM42Ay')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

Comment: I am very new to JS and I believe what im trying to do is not NodeJS because I am just trying to do this in a simple webpage and not in a application

Comment: @RichardCooper Then it should work. Which browser are you using? Coz the error message looks similar to that of Node JS. Can you show a screenshot of where the error comes up, please? You're running it on Node JS instance in Paiza.io. Use [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) or [CodePen](https://codepen.io/) for running your code please. And here... [Paiza runs on Node JS not on Browser](https://i.imgur.com/VrB1bO2.png).

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushotaman I have run the code on this project url https://paiza.io/projects/_BDmlB6wi4TZEWMZ8qawkg

Comment: @RichardCooper You're running it on Node JS instance in Paiza.io. Use [**CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/) or [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/) for running your code on browser, please. And here... [Paiza runs on Node JS not on Browser](https://i.imgur.com/VrB1bO2.png).

Comment: @RichardCooper Sure... Waiting.

Comment: I ran the code in codepen but the preview still remains blank when it should come out something like 0.008

Comment: this is the error i get in CodeSandbox i believe i chose the correct project type

Comment: @RichardCooper It works for me: https://codepen.io/astrotim/pen/vGgmXr?html-preprocessor=pug

Comment: @RichardCooper It shows unexpected token. So it means something is wrong in the fetching URL. Can you send me the CodeSandbox URL please?

Comment: @RichardCooper Got it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-sea-86zw9 Let me update it and send you.

Comment: @RichardCooper Haven't you saved it? Can you press `Ctrl + S` to save it?

Comment: @RichardCooper Fixed. You should use this way: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-bhaskara-sksve?file=/src/index.js. I'll update the answer.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-sea-86zw9?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @RichardCooper Check my answer, it has a snippet. Refresh and see, it works. Here's the working code: **https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-bhaskara-sksve?file=/src/index.js:0-181**

Comment: @RichardCooper [I got **`0.00842138`** in my body...](https://i.imgur.com/f2zuVyj.png)